# Class for hyperlink styling in css not working

Tags: html, css

I have general hyperlink styling in my css and trying to create a new class to modify the font size. It's not working and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```css
a:hover,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a.audio,
a.audio:hover,
a.audio:link,
a.audio:visited,
a.audio:active {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
Audio by <a class='audio' href=linkaddress target=_blank>name</a>
```

Comment: But...the code snippet you provided seems to apply the styling just fine? `!important` shouldn't be necessary in this case, anyways.

Comment: What is not working ? I can see the updated font ?

Comment: Describe "It's not working "

Comment: In your first CSS rule, I'd also include just `a` with no pseudo class to cover all your bases.

Comment: It's just not working. When I change the font in the css for the regular a style, the font in my link changes, so it's clearly reacting to the regular one. When I delete the regular styling, it's still not picking up on the a.audio styling. It's simply not seeing it.

Comment: I know it makes no sense and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Also, though not _required_, I'd put quotes around the HTML attributes `href="linkaddress"` and `target="_blank"`

Comment: Can you provide an example of it not working? The code you've provided works fine, so the problem doesn't lie here; there must be more. And have you confirmed it's not a stylesheet caching issue?

Comment: I've put quotes around the link and added "a" to the first styling, to cover my bases... 

I don't think it's a caching issue. When I change the font to 14px for the regular styling, the font immediately changes. It's just not reacting to the other class style. I had someone else here who's good at html look at it, and he can't figure it out either.

Comment: I'm close to giving up. Is there a work-around?

Comment: @WandaEmbar there is no workaround because your problem (*as described in this question*) does not exist. You code (*even without the `!important`*) works just as expected. So it must be elsewhere.

Comment: I renamed my stylesheet and it's still not working. It's definitely not a caching issue.

Comment: expanding on @GabyakaG.Petrioli, your code works just as expected in this isolated example on Stack Overflow, so the problem exists outside of the 20 lines of CSS you included here.  If you want to give us a more complete example without revealing the domain you're working on, you can create a JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) with ALL of your CSS and HTML.  Chances are another CSS rule is overriding what you have here.

Comment: When I put the styling straight in the <a tag, it's still not working. <a style='font-size:14px' href='... Shouldn't this at least work?

Comment: @WandaEmbar perhaps you have `!important` on some other rule that affects text. Use the developer tools and check the applied classes/styles on that element (*through the DOM inspector*)

Comment: The link I'm trying to modify is an entry in an array and kind of buried deep into my code. My work-around now is to change the styles of the other links on my site (there aren't too many) and have this one react to the regular a styling. This is working. So I got a work-around. Thanks so much to everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Stack Snippet works, I can't pinpoint exactly why your hyperlink styling isn't working but what I think is happening is something is probably taking dominance over what you're declaring. I think that you should try a couple of things:

1) Open your developer tools in your browser. If you are on the elements tab, you can select your class and see what styling is being applied to it. Here is an example of mine:

[(what my audio class looks like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zGNr.png)

As you can see the font-size I was getting for the audio class was 14px. However, the font-size I declared for all links was crossed out. It isn't applied because the styling for the audio class is more specific.

If you open up your developer tools, it can give you more insight on why your styling isn't being applied. Maybe something is overriding your styling.

2) Try and put your styling to the end of your CSS file and make sure that if you have other stylesheets it is the last stylesheet that is mentioned. Since CSS is cascading, things that are declared last take more dominance.

Hope this helps!! @_kcodes

Comment: Thanks! It's still not clear why it's not picking up on the class styling, but I did a work-around which is functioning fine enough. I appreciate your help!